# Lamp wiring - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: electrical

Trying to wire up a new lamp socket, seems to be rated for 250V, 250W. There are four conductors, white, black, and two other wires in this clear insulation. Please see pictures. There is 120V between the two clear wires twisted together and no voltage between any other wires. I wired it like it was wired on the old socket and I guess I drew way too much current as it blew a hole in the power cord and started smoking. I was assuming black is hot, white is neutral, but the other two cords I have no idea why there is voltage between them. I feel pretty stupid, can anyone help?

UPDATE - There are two actual lamps, one has no switch and is on with power, the other has the switch. Looks like the black and white wires are hooked up to the lamp that is always on. So I guess the black wire is screwed on the same terminal as one of the clear wires and the white with the other? Theres still three terminals on the socket which is confusing.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/34pezhe.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/2lkcg7p.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm concerned you're going  to electrocute yourself or someone else, and your first picture, where you have both terminals of the lamp cord on the same screw, is Exhibit A. If you really want our help, unplug everything and post a diagram showing all the wiring in the lamp.

Comment: Socket is rated 250V, but you mention 120V measurement, which would be typical for US wiring. While many items (for convenience of manufacturers to not have to stock multiple rated items) will be rated 250V, in the US residential lighting is normally 120V. (Only certain large appliances are normally 240V.) So please confirm location and planned actual usage (voltage) of light fixture.